# Header in left column layout

Tags: layout, navigation, header, column

Can anyone please tell me how we can make header in left column so header will be moved to left side. I have attached the website screenshot how i want. any help will be most most appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Amit Mishra,Just goto  cut the code `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>`.

Then put the code under `<div class="col-left sidebar"> .....</div>`

Comment: @AmitMishra feel free to accept the answer if it worked for you.